# Are homonyms inherently unstable?

Tags: homonymy

I'm certain there's a better way to entitle this question, so maybe someone can edit it.

Consider the word the word "we'll".  My understanding of the Fill-Feel Merger means "we'll" could end up sounding like "wheel".  In fact, I'm pretty sure I've heard that pronunciation in a southern and/or Black English.

Assuming that does become the prominent pronunciation, does that imply that the pronunciation of "wheel" will change?  I imagine there are other examples of homonyms developing in this way.  Does one word typically "win" over time and keep its pronunciation longer?  I guess I'm asking if homonyms change at a greater rate than other words; and, of so, is there a pattern to it like: the more frequently used word "wins" or is more resistant to change?

Comment: This is just a side comment, but the pin-pen merger isn't relevant to "we'll" and "wheel". The pin-pen merger is a merger of the sounds /ɪ/ (as in "kit") and /ɛ/ (as in "dress") before a nasal consonant (/n/, /m/, or /ŋ/ as in "sing"--although in some accents vowels before /ŋ/ have special further changes). The word "wheel" is usually pronounced /wiːl/, with the /iː/ vowel of "fleece" and the non-nasal final consonant /l/.

Comment: "We'll" and "wheel" -aren't- already the same? (I thought I spoke standard GenAmE)

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure.  I'm from NY so maybe I say it with an accent.  I say "will".

Comment: If (like myself) you pronounce `we'll` and `wheel ` the same, that's usually the WINE-WHINE merger, affecting the _consonants_. I've not heard the vowels being pronounced differently, but I'll have to do some more research.

Comment: The merger of *We'll* and *wheel* (*fill–feel* merger) is independent of the *pin–pen* merger and is observed in the US South and, indeed, Black English. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Fill%E2%80%93feel_merger

Comment: This may answer your question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12414

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @nardog Surely the relevant example for the FILL-FEEL merger is `will` - `we'll`.

Comment: @Michaelyus Oops, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Nardog wait, which way is it going?

Comment: @dwstein A merger is a merger - it doesn't necessarily mean one is merging with the other and oftentimes the result is intermediate. In *fill–feel* in particular, though, I think the common result is something like [fijəɫ] .

Comment: @Nardog I think they are asking a related but different question.